# Best way to mimick Apple's iPad2 slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have a link on my homepage that, when clicked, is replaced with a div containing the elements that make up a slideshow. I'd only show 5 slides maximum but wanted to see what's the best way to implement something like this.

I like the way Apple's slideshow operates at http://www.apple.com/ipad/

I've got a book that walks me through some jQuery to create a basic slideshow but I was wondering if a plugin like Cycle would be best here? I don't really want to include another script in my app's header but I'm not ruling it out.

Comment: The [Slides](http://slidesjs.com/) plugin looks similar-ish.

Comment: I just implemented Slides and it's great. I need to figure out how to manage the script files better, but that's another question. Can you add this as an answer so I can accept you?

Comment: Glad you found it suitable. Answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Slides](http://slidesjs.com/) plugin looks similar-ish.

Comment: Perfect, and extremely easy to get running.